# How to customize web-app (pages and UI) for different customers

Tags: asp.net, customization

We have an ASP.NET web-application which has become difficult to maintain, and I'm looking for ideas on how to redesign it. It's an employee administration system which can be highly customized for each of our customers. Let me explain how it works now:

On the default page we have a menu where a user can select a task, such as Create Employee or View Timesheet. I'll use Create Employee as an example.

When a user selects Create Employee from the menu, an ASPX page is loaded which contains a dynamically loaded usercontrol for the selected menuitem, e.g. for Create Employee this would be AddEmployee.ascx

If the user clicks Save on the control, it navigates to the default page.
Some menuitems involve multiple steps, so if the user clicks Next on a multi-step flow then it will navigate to the next page in the flow, and so on until it reaches the final step, where clicking Save navigates to the default page.

Some customers may require an extra step in the Create Employee flow (e.g. SecurityClearance.ascx) but others may not.

Different customers may use the same ASCX usercontrol, so in the AddEmployee.OnInit we can customize the fields for that customer, i.e. making certain fields hidden or readonly or mandatory.

The following things are customizable per customer:

- Menu items
- Steps in each flow (ascx control names)
- Hidden fields in each ascx
- Mandatory fields in each ascx
- Rules relating to each ascx, which allows certain logic to be used in the code for that customer

The customizations are held in a huge XML file per customer, which could be 7500 lines long.

Is there any framework or rules-engine that we could use to customize our application in this way? How do other applications manage customizations per customer?

Comment: Good question: however, a better spot would be programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: cross-posted to Programmers: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/175941/how-to-customize-web-app-pages-and-ui-for-different-customers

Answer (score 3):

If your regular data is held in a database I'm not entirely sure why you'd want to have all of that customer specific information in an xml file.  Move it into the database.

Next, there are many different kinds of rules engines out there.  Considering you're using asp.net you might want to look at Windows Workflow for at least some of this.  You might read the following: http://karlreinsch.com/2010/02/05/microsoft-rule-engines/

A long time ago I used a product called Haley Rules to drive a c# web app.  It controlled everything from the screens that were available right down to the fields that appeared and whether they were required or not.  It took awhile to get the team on board with how it worked, but once that happened bringing on a new client was extremely simple.  Haley was since gobbled up by Oracle, but was probably the absolute best one out there.

Others you might be interested in are [NxBRE](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nxbre/) and even [nCalc](http://ncalc.codeplex.com/).  NxBRE is an actual rules engine which is a port of one built for java.  nCalc on the other hand isn't a rules engine per se.  However, if you can express your logic in simple boolean statements then it is extremely fast.  I'm currently using this to drive page flow in one of our applications.

Some commercial ones include: [FlexRule](http://www.flexrule.com/), [iLog](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/websphere/ilog/)

Answer (score 2):

Your existing rule engine tool supports your web application, which means it meets your needs already. You can use other "Rule Engine" like MS work flow, but IMO it can also end with a hard to maitain situation.

Let's say there is registration portal. It collects general user infomation and save them into database. Simple. we build one protal for one client with several ASCXs and Rules.Then for another client,we add more rules and more controls to these ASCXs. Working in this way, sooner or later we will reach the final straw client. At that time the code base is hard to maitain and devs lost themselves in lots of rules. It is what happened to me.

So to me, it is not about which Rule engine to use.

Then How?

I have raised a question, and one of the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12267135/407183) makes sense to me( thought not a picked answer). In this answer, the guy mentioned what kind of company you are. In your question it is more like which department you are or do you want to seperate your dev teams.

If you are in a archetect teams, build a framework with a rule engine. Create a basic registraion portal as a sample portal.Make DAO,BO decoupled with UI (Seperate layers).

If you are in a customise teams, create customised user control (dont reuse these user control in basic version). What you will recreate is just UI, you can still use DAO,BO as they are not defined in user control, they are at other layers. In this way you get the freedom to define your client specified rules without worring about contaminating other clients rules or introducing new bugs to other client's registrations.

Just realise it is not like an answer to your question. Anyway it is my thoughts after limited xp of working on a engine rule based ,multi-clients web application.